# Like, share button not showing

Tags: facebook

I have this  website  http://smithachallathomas.net63.net/. Now I am trying to add a  share, like, comment stream. I made this website using php.

Here's my index.php

```
<?php include('Header.php'); ?>

<div id = "content">
<div class = "post">
<h2></h2>
<p>


<p>Body BodyLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod leo vitae nulla euismod commodo. Phasellus at mi quam. 
Etiam lacinia elit pellentesque ligula faucibus nec luctus mi mollis. Duis ante elit, blandit sed placerat sit amet, varius vitae tellus. 
Duis in ante sed metus mollis ornare. Donec ipsum lorem, mollis non ultrices et, porta at dolor. Sed nisi mauris, condimentum nec vehicula 
</p>



</div>
</div>

<?php include('Sidebar.php'); ?>

<fb:like href="http://www.http://smithachallathomas.net63.net/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
<?php include('Footer.php'); ?>
```

**Header.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head>
Blog for healthy living
</head>
<body>
Healthy living practices 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=******";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</body>
```

I dont see the like/share button on the  webpage. Please help me. I am assuming that once someone likes this I will be shown on my facebook wall page 
PS: this is just some website I did to test out the share, like, comments.

Thanks
Sun

Comment: First of all you are closing your <body> in the header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put `http://www.http://`. Try fixing that:

```
<fb:like href="http://smithachallathomas.net63.net/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
```

Also, you appear to be missing the `http:` beginning on your JavaScript source line, here:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=******";
```

Just minor things that would cause problems. I'm no Facebook API expert though.

Comment: Thanku It works now. I have one mor question. Is it very hard to do this like, share on aspx page. I will try the comment stream now.

Comment: The `js.src` line is supposed to be missing the `http:`, so that it will inherit the same protocol (http or https) as the main page.